# Batch command to trim spaces in CSV

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I am trying to avoid PowerShell if possible.

Looking for an way to use Windows batch command to read a text CSV file (number of columns could vary) and trim the spaces. Leading and trailing spaces must go but rest must be preserved

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know CSV format, but I do know Batch. If you post a sample CSV file before and after the Batch process (with a short explanation of when to remove spaces) it is very possible to write a solution Batch file.

Comment: BAT handles lots of things fairly poorly  ...and the poorest of all is string handling. Something like TRIM(...) seems drop-dead simple - but in fact for BAT controlling such a thing can be quite difficult. It's probably not impossible, but there are definitely better ways.

Comment: here're some trim implementations: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to remove spaces 
 - at end and begin of line
 - before and after any separator

I suppose you separator will be consistent through files, so let it inside script instead of parameter.
The script suppose there is not separator character inside the values (this could happen with strings).
If you need to handle more special chars (like tab), you should add matching blocks.
! replace % when you use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). I needed to do this so the variable is well parsed in sub blocks.

Explanation:

For each line, check for each case. 
    While a case is found, loop through it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Remove spaces from csv
:: ARGS:
:: 1 : file name of the CSV file

set _SEP=;
dir /b %1  2>&1 >nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo ERROR : File not found & goto :EOF

del %1.trimmed 2>nul

for /f "delims=%_SEP% tokens=*" %%L in (%1) do (
echo before: %%L
set _LINE=%%L

call :CHECK_BEFORE
call :CHECK_AFTER
call :CHECK_BEGIN
call :CHECK_END

echo !_LINE! >> %1.trimmed
)

echo END of TRIM
echo output is in %1.trimmed
goto :EOF


:TRIM_BEFORE_SEP
set _LINE=!_LINE: ;=;!
goto :EOF

:TRIM_AFTER_SEP
set _LINE=!_LINE:; =;!
goto :EOF

:TRIM_BEGIN
set _LINE=!_LINE:~1!
goto :EOF

:TRIM_END
set _LINE=!_LINE:~0,-1!
goto :EOF

:CHECK_BEFORE
echo !_LINE! | findstr /C:" ;"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 call :TRIM_BEFORE_SEP & goto CHECK_BEFORE
echo End Step: Trim Before Sep
goto :EOF

:CHECK_AFTER
echo !_LINE! | findstr /C:"; "
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 call :TRIM_AFTER_SEP & goto CHECK_AFTER
echo End Step: Trim After Sep
goto :EOF

:CHECK_BEGIN
if "!_LINE:~0,1!" == " " call :TRIM_BEGIN & goto CHECK_BEGIN
echo End Step: Trim Begin
goto :EOF

:CHECK_END
if "!_LINE:~-1!" == " " call :TRIM_END & goto CHECK_END
echo End Step: Trim End
goto :EOF
```

HTH
I might not be very good at explaining, so don't mind to ask for details.